# GWT and WebServices (wsdl)

Tags: java, gwt, wsdl, webservice-client

Can anyone point me a way to access WSDL webservices from a GWT client? Is that even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: "from a GWT client" can you elaborate

Comment: I don't want to write server code, just create a html+js+css website using GWT, that calls remote webservices to get data.

Answer (score 2):

[Smart GWT](http://www.smartclient.com/product/index.jsp) has support for WSDL data sources.

Other than that, you can always wrap the WSDL transactions in the usual GWT RPC on the server side and interface through that.

Comment: For SmartGWT we have to use the commercial version, because I need the HttpProxy, which is needed because of th4e same-origin policy restriction. So it doesn't seem to fit me.

About the GWT RPC, I don't want to write server classes, because I want just to write a simple html+js+css site using GWT, no server code.

Comment: @infinito: So you want to go cross domain? Might want to include that in the question since it's going to be real challenge here. You might want to read up on some of the cross-domain XML tricks. It's most likely going to require either iframe exploits or a server component to do it cleanly. Also, you can write your own proxy servlet in a couple minutes to avoid paying for Smart GWT. There's literally hundreds of examples if you google for it.

Comment: @j flemm: I've finally got it working using RequestBuilder and an Apache proxypass to avoid the cross-domain stuff.